# How to display jQuery Validate error message after Bootstrap's add-on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap

Currently it is display right after the input field, so it is between input field and before .add-on, which is incorrect - see [the demo](http://jsbin.com/ukecog/3).
How can it be corrected? (please also note that I use [customized errorPlacement](http://jsbin.com/ukecog/3/edit#source) - this functionality should remain unchanged)

Answer (score 2):

For a generic solution to always print it after any bootstrap add-on elements use the following:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
var next = element.next();
if (next.hasClass('add-on'))
  $(error).insertAfter(next);
else
  $(error).insertAfter(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
$(error).insertAfter($(element));
```

To

```
$(error).insertAfter($(element).parent());
```

Or you cannot modify that js code? If so, it'll be necessary to create css hack or just change HTML markup.

Comment: I can modify that and your approach works well for input fields with addon, but doesn't work well for field without it. Can I verify in the code somehow if addon field is there and apply `.parent` only in such cases?

Comment: What's the relationship? element - it's your input. It does not depend on span add-on. Sample: http://jsbin.com/ayuyid/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Please see this demo (input just 1 symbol into first field) - http://jsbin.com/ukecog/5/edit

Comment: OK, I am testing `$(error).appendTo($(element).parent("div.controls"));` now.